# Can we call serializer class using a string in Django rest frame work?

Tags: django, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework

This is the object we are using to get serializer class

```
   serializer_obj = {
                        'Check Layout Query': 'ChecklayoutQueryViewSerializer', 
                        'Check Remitter Query': 'RemitterQueryViewSerializer', 
                        'Check Processing Query': 'ProcessQueryViewSerializer'
                    }
```

I want to use the key of above dictionary to get the serializer class:

```
serializer = ProcessQueryViewSerializer(queryset, many=True)
```

I'm trying to do in this way:

```
serializer = serialier_obj['Check Processing Query'](queryset, many=True)
```

But unfortunately I'm getting error :

> str obj is not callable

Comment: do you have any particular reason to keep dict's values as str?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error suggests, you're trying to use a `str` as a `callable`. You should change your `serializer_obj` to something like this:

```
serializer_obj = {
    'Check Layout Query': ChecklayoutQueryViewSerializer, 
    'Check Remitter Query': RemitterQueryViewSerializer, 
    'Check Processing Query': ProcessQueryViewSerializer
}
```

Using the actual classes/functions and not a string.